# Creating sale.order.line from web service (IMPORTING) ? Odoo V9e

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

If there is only one product in memo_data['items'] the sale order line will be created but if there are two or more products it will be reefused with an error: Too many values to unpack. 
Here is the code:

```
for item in memo_data['items']:
                    c_id = self.env['sale.order.line'].search([('creditmemo_id','=',memo_data['creditmemo_id'])])
                    if not c_id:
                        _logger.info("THIS IS CID: %s" % memo_data['creditmemo_id'])
                        a_product = self.env['product.product'].search([('default_code', '=',item['sku'])])
                        if a_product:
                            _logger.info("FOUND THE PRODUCT with id: %s" %a_product.id)
                            pos_price = float(item['row_total'])

                            neg_price = pos_price - (2 * pos_price)

                            res12 = {


                                'order_id':         is_exist.id,

                                'product_id':       a_product.id,

                                'price_unit':       neg_price,
                                'sequence':         10,


                                'product_uom_qty':   float(item['qty']),

                                'creditmemo_id' :   memo_data['creditmemo_id'],

                                'creditmemo_date':  memo_data['created_at'],

                                'creditmemo_increment_id' : memo_data['increment_id'],



                            }


                            self.env['sale.order.line'].create(res12)`enter code here`
```

Comment: post error log for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

i assume you are trying to loop the list of records. but inside loop try to change memo_data to item:

```
for item in memo_data['items']:
                    c_id = self.env['sale.order.line'].search([('creditmemo_id','=',item['creditmemo_id'])])
                    if not c_id:
                        _logger.info("THIS IS CID: %s" % item['creditmemo_id'])
                        a_product = self.env['product.product'].search([('default_code', '=',item['sku'])])
                        if a_product:
                            _logger.info("FOUND THE PRODUCT with id: %s" %a_product.id)
                            pos_price = float(item['row_total'])

                            neg_price = pos_price - (2 * pos_price)

                            res12 = {


                                'order_id':         is_exist.id,

                                'product_id':       a_product.id,

                                'price_unit':       neg_price,
                                'sequence':         10,


                                'product_uom_qty':   float(item['qty']),

                                'creditmemo_id' :   item['creditmemo_id'],

                                'creditmemo_date':  item['created_at'],

                                'creditmemo_increment_id' : item['increment_id'],



                            }
```

Comment: nope, i need memo_data['creditmemo_id'] becuase it is the carrier of the main information, the item from memo_data['items'] are the actual credit memo lines that need to be inserted. BTW i got 2300 memos imported using this code, only 20 out of 2320 were refused with this error:

Comment: please post sample of memo_data

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to handle your dict like this

```
for field, possible_values in fields.iteritems():
    print field, possible_values
```

python 2.7 : iteritems()
python 3: items().

Thanks